Error showing when using ImageMagick compare
I have created what I hope to be a lossless .jp2 file from a .tif using ImageMagick.
for %%a in (*.tif) do magick "%%a" -quality 0 "%%~na.jp2"
I'd like to check that the conversion is lossless and so have used the command:
for %%a in (*.jp2) do magick compare -verbose  "%%a" "%%~na.tif" -metric RMSE
After listing the details of the two files, this returns an error:
magick compare -verbose  "DSC09906.jp2" "DSC09906.tif" -metric RMSE
DSC09906.jp2 JP2 5463x3851 5463x3851+0+0 16-bit sRGB 84.1136MiB 7.566u 0:07.566
DSC09906.tif TIFF 5463x3851 5463x3851+0+0 16-bit TrueColor sRGB 120.385MiB 0.126u 0:00.126
compare:  `RMSE' @ error/compare.c/CompareImagesCommand/1159
Is this error the difference between the two files (I was hoping for a 0) or have a I made a mistake in the way I have asked the comparison to be made?
Many thanks :-)

Your Imagemagick syntax is likely in error.  You have the ordering wrong --- put the metric before the images-- and I do not see any output image for the comparison result.  So for a given image, perhaps you should use the following syntax
magick compare -verbose -metric RMSE "DSC09906.jp2" "DSC09906.tif"  compare_result.jp2


The default for JP2 quality (in DB) is lossless. See https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php
I am not sure why you might want the output compare image to be JP2.  Nevertheless, the above syntax should work. If you do not want the output compare image, the use NULL: in its place.

Hi , thanks for your answer and link showing the default quality setting. I'd tried the order in a few different ways without luck - unfortunately with your suggestion above I get the error:
magick -verbose -metric RMSE "DSC09906.jp2" "DSC09906.tif"  compare_result.jp2
magick: no images found for operation `-metric' at CLI arg 2 @ error/operation.c/CLIOption/5479.
I'd hoped to get a numerical output for the differences, rather than an image showing the differences - is that possible or do I need to specify an output file?

I made a mistake in my answer. You need the compare in the command.  For some reason I was thinking magick convert, which should only be magick. But as I said above if you do not want the output image and want just the numerical value, use NULL: in place of the output image. magick compare -verbose -metric rmse image1 image2 null:
